# How to access user profile information in firebase through getUser()

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using cloud functions as a means to send users push notifications for my app. I am following the template set by google [Here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js). The problem I have is that I dont really understand Javascript well and I have my user profile data stored within a profile node. When I call the **getUser()** function I am not able to access the user info within the profile node. How can I access the data within the users profile node so that I can display their "username" and "profileImage" in the push notifications.

**Data Structure**

users/uid/profile/Dictionary(key/val pairings here for data).

**Google Data Structure**

users/uid/displayName

**Cloud Function:**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendPushNotificationRep = functions.database.ref('/recieved-friend-requests/{userId}/{friendId}').onWrite(event => {

const userID = event.params.userId;
const friendID = event.params.friendId;


if (!event.data.val()) {
    return;
}

const getDeviceTokensPromise = admin.database().ref(`/users/${userID}/fcmToken`).once('value');


// Get the follower profile.
const getRepProfilePromise = admin.auth().getUser(friendID);


return Promise.all([getDeviceTokensPromise, getRepProfilePromise]).then(results => {
    const tokensSnapshot = results[0];
    const friend = results[1];

    if (!tokensSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
        return console.log('There are no notification tokens to send to.');
    }

    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: 'Rep Request!',
            body: `${friend.username} sent you a request`,
            badge: '1',
            sound: 'default',
            icon: 'logo3'
        }
    };

    const tokens = Object.keys(tokensSnapshot.val());

    // Send notifications to all tokens.
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload).then(response => {
        // For each message check if there was an error.
            const tokensToRemove = [];
            response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
            const error = result.error;
             if (error) {
                 console.error('Failure sending notification to', tokens[index], error);
            // Cleanup the tokens who are not registered anymore.
            if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' ||
                error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
                tokensToRemove.push(tokensSnapshot.ref.child(tokens[index]).remove());
                 }
             }
        });
        return Promise.all(tokensToRemove);
    });
});
```

});

Comment: Possible for you to include the relevant source code you are currently using to attempt to get *their "username" and "profileImage"* and can you give detail of what you are getting when trying to call `getUser()`? Any errors or return from that?

Comment: No errors. The notification returns "undefined" within the notification